# Bug in CALayer's shadowPath?

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, core-graphics, calayer

I'm trying to draw a custom-shaped shadow using `CALayer`:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation ZKSBAppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSView *view = self.window.contentView;
    view.wantsLayer = YES;

    CALayer *shadowLayer = [CALayer layer];
    shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 1;
    shadowLayer.shadowRadius = 1;
    shadowLayer.shadowOffset = NSMakeSize(0, 0);

    CGMutablePathRef shadowPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    // setting the following rect's width to 100 fixes everything.
    // setting it to 130 screws the shadow even more.
    CGPathAddRect(shadowPath, NULL, CGRectMake(4, 0, 120, 48));
    CGPathAddRect(shadowPath, NULL, CGRectMake(120, 50, 116, 48));
    shadowLayer.shadowPath = shadowPath;
    CGPathRelease(shadowPath);

    [view.layer addSublayer:shadowLayer];
}
@end
```

You can create an empty Cocoa project in Xcode, replace your app.delegate's .m file content with the above code and try it yourself.

It looks like specific shadow path geometry causes `CALayer` to go nuts.

For example:

```
CGPathAddRect(shadowPath, NULL, CGRectMake(4, 0, 100, 48));
CGPathAddRect(shadowPath, NULL, CGRectMake(120, 50, 116, 48));
```

This one looks perfectly okay:

[image: Okay case]

Now I'm going to make the 1st rectangle wider by 20 points:

```
CGPathAddRect(shadowPath, NULL, CGRectMake(4, 0, 120, 48));
CGPathAddRect(shadowPath, NULL, CGRectMake(120, 50, 116, 48));
```

[image: Whoa case]

...doesn't look so good anymore. Plus 10 points:

```
CGPathAddRect(shadowPath, NULL, CGRectMake(4, 0, 130, 48));
CGPathAddRect(shadowPath, NULL, CGRectMake(120, 50, 116, 48));
```

[image: WTF case]

Now that is plain wrong, isn't it?

So, the question is: what the hell is going on, am I doing it wrong or something? Do you think it's a bug and I should file a report?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that sounds like a bug. Even if it's not, by filing a bug report Apple should respond and give you useful information.

Comment: Yes, **definitely** file a report. Apple engineers most likely won't discover these kinds of things unless we inform them.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist it could have been a mistake on my part, didn't want to raise a false alarm.

Comment: Hi zrxq, any luck on this problem? I'm seeing similar things when I try to add shadows to my bar graph (i.e. path with multiple rectangulars), and it shows up totally wrong, like your second image.

Comment: Encountered this same problem myself. In the end the only workaround I had was to reconstruct the shape layer with multiple shape layers, one for each distinct rectangle. It's still present as of the iOS 6.1 SDK

Comment: This bug is now fixed by Apple.

Comment: @zrxq, did Apple respond to your bug report and say that the bug is fixed in a specific OS version? if so, which version? Can you post an answer to the thread, with a summary of the information from Apple?

Comment: `We believe this issue has been addressed in OS X Mavericks GM build 13A603.  Please verify with this release, and update this report with your results.`

Comment: Not posting as an answer until I test it thoroughly.